# javaout typemap doesn't work for std::vector

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

When I'm using `int` everything works fine -

```
%immutable S::field;

%typemap(javaout) int S::field {
  //custom code
}

struct S {
  int field;
};
```

But approach doesn't work for `std::vector<int>`

```
%include <std_vector.i>

%immutable S::field;
%template(vector_int) std::vector<int>;

%typemap(javaout) std::vector<int> S::field {
  //custom code
}

struct S {
  std::vector<int> field;
};
```

Samples were compiled with `swig -java -c++ -module sample sample.i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Swig docs on [structure data members](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_structure_data_members).

The key point is:

> When a **structure** member is wrapped, it is handled as a pointer, unless the `%naturalvar` directive is used where it is handled more like a C++ reference.

So the typemap you need to define is

```
%typemap(javaout) std::vector<int>* S::field {
    //custom code
}
```

(or `%typemap(javaout) std::vector<int>& S::field` if you are using `%naturalvar`).